# Getting error while running springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Not able to run spring boot application

Tried removing contents of `/C:/Users/SaurKumar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.10.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar`

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2019-09-08 05:22:05.217  INFO 2420 --- [           main] i.j.c.CourseApiDataApplication           : Starting CourseApiDataApplication on BLRLW8166 with PID 2420 (C:\Users\SaurKumar\Downloads\course-api-data\course-api-data\target\classes started by saurkumar in C:\Users\SaurKumar\Downloads\course-api-data\course-api-data)
2019-09-08 05:22:05.222  INFO 2420 --- [           main] i.j.c.CourseApiDataApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-08 05:22:06.110  INFO 2420 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-08 05:22:06.215 ERROR 2420 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.postProcess(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:121)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/SaurKumar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.10.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/SaurKumar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.10.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource


Process finished with exit code 1
-----------------------------------------
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>course-api-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>course-api-data</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs, it seems `Spring` is picking a different version for groupId `org.springframework.data` than the one provided with `spring-data-jpa`. If you could match the versions of `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-data-jpa`, it should work.

Quick fix being: Remove the version number for `spring-data-jpa` and it will by default take the latest version, which in your case is `2.1.10.RELEASE`.